# Бесконечный вложенный цикл for в JS

Tags: javascript, for

Всем привет! Можете объяснить почему цикл стал бесконечным? Пытаюсь изучить циклы, но выходит как-то непонятно.

```js
let abc = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
    abc += 1;
    console.log(abc);
  }
};
```

Comment: Что значит "стал"? А когда он не был бесконечным?

Answer (score 5):

Всё просто:

```
for ( let j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
                        ^----- Проблема тут
```

Из-за недосмотра переменная `j` никогда не увеличивается и поэтому условие `j < 5` всегда истинно